# How to route all GET requests to a one controller function

Tags: playframework

Is it posible to define in routes file that all types of request  GET, POST, PUT etc.
will be handled by one controller ?

`GET      /AlltypeOfUrl       controllers.Application.getHendler(allParams)
POST     /AlltypeOfUrl       controllers.Application.postHendler()
DELETE   /AlltypeOfUrl       controllers.Application.deleteHandler(params)`

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is described in **[Routing](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting)** documentation as

***Dynamic parts spanning several /***

Simplest sample is (second one for catching URLs with trailing slash, although it should be handled [in other way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196239/1066240)) :

```
GET   /*allParams    controllers.Application.getHendler(allParams)
GET   /*allParams/   controllers.Application.getHendler(allParams)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you have above is allowed.

But if by "all type of url" you mean *, then you hypothetically could do this

```
GET      /*      controllers.Application.getHendler(allParams)
POST     /*       controllers.Application.postHendler()
DELETE   /*       controllers.Application.deleteHandler(params)
```

But then i guess you would not care to host any static content (ie javascript)-- your public folder becomes useless because all your routes are going thru your custom controller.

if you just purely want to handle all routing on your own, then yes you can.

You can find more info on routing here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaRouting