# Best practices for play routes with pagination?

Tags: scala, pagination, routes, playframework-2.0

I'm fairly new to Play 2 (Scala). I need to use pagination to output the members of a list. This is easy enough, except the pagination part.

In my route file I have my search:

```
GET        /find/thing/:type        controllers.Application.showType(type: String)
```

This works fine if I wanted to dump the entire list to the page.

Now, what if I want to paginate it? I suppose I could do -

```
GET        /find/thing/:type/:page        controllers.Application.showType(type: String, page: Int)
```

But then what happens if the user just types "myurl.com/find/thing/bestThing" without the page? Clearly there will be an error when it should automatically "default" to page 1.

Is there a way to default these arguments? If not, what is the best practice for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

1. declare both routes you mentioned (first using [parameter with fixed value](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting#Parameters-with-fixed-values)), then you can use [untrail trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13196239/1066240) globally, in such case it will redirect your `/find/thing/something/` to `/find/thing/something` (page=1)
2. You can use [parameters with default values](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting#Parameters-with-default-values), then your route will be like:

   ```
   GET /find/thing/:type  controllers.Application.showType(type: String, page: Int ?= 1)
   ```

and genereted URL will be like:

```
/find/thing/something?page=123
```

Comment: Thank you, chosen because your answer has more than one good solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a query string parameter instead of a path parameter for the page number. Query string parameters will allow you to provide default values for when the parameter is missing.

```
GET   /find/thing/:type      controllers.Application.showType(type: String, page: Int ?= 1)
```

You would use them like this:

```
/find/thing/bestThing?page=3    // shows page 3

/find/thing/bestThing           // shows page 1
```